# How do I play video on JWPlayer whenever my live stream is offline?

Tags: embed, customization, jwplayer, live-streaming, playlist

I'm trying to get JWPlayer to run a playlist of video whenever my live stream is off air.. Does anyone know if this is possible? Right now as it sits, when the RTMP live feed is off there's just a still image. I want to entertain the viewers when its off, and then stop the playback of stored videos when the stream starts back up, I've seen this feature available with ustream and want to duplicate it some how.

I'm currently trying to use this code but when we go live, or are live it just plays our youtube video instead.

```
<script src="http://wpc.E74E.edgecastcdn.net/20394R/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div class="contentcontainer">
<div id='playerjxUzssOPWgxB'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('playerjxUzssOPWgxB').setup({
file: 'rtmp://fml.E74E.edgecastcdn.net/20394R/Streamname',
image: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-$
width: '635',
height: '360',
autostart: 'true',
primary: 'html5',
playlist: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLkfH4h937hyiJT-A-NxicPiyASEjXXPSV?v=2&alt=rss',
rtmp: { subscribe: true }});
</script>
<div id="chatnow"></div>
</div>
```

Debug URL is http://bargainsbeyond.com

Thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to try something using our API - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message

Basically, the stream is offline, so playing the stream will load() another file in the jw player and then play() it, and when that player reaches onComplete(), the page reloads.

Comment: I implemented the code and ran into some issues, I also posted at for you to see as well: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6999650-autoplay-video-when-live-stream-is-offline

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting that there, but you didn't provide a link, that is needed for further debugging.

Comment: Hi ethan, thanks for your reply, I went ahead and posted a link above for you to the domain the script is embeded on

Comment: I replied to you there.